# Scheme. Tail recursive?

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

any tail-recursive version for the below mentioned pseudocode ? Thanks !

```
(define (min list)
  (cond 
   ((null? list) '())
   ((null? (cdr list)) (car list))
   (#t (let ((a (car list))
             (b (min (cdr list))))
         (if (< b a) b a)))))
```

Comment: Here's a spoiler: http://inferretuation.blogspot.com/2008/05/lists-and-lists-tail-recursive-fun.html If this is for homework, you may not want to read it until you've submitted your own answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on the [`fold` higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Comment: In Scheme, `fold` is provided with SRFI 1 (http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html). If you're using PLT, say `(require srfi/1)`. If using Guile, say `(use-modules (srfi srfi-1))`. For other implementations, read their respective manual. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Define a helper function that takes a list and the smallest element found so far (let's call it b). If the list is empty, it should return b, otherwise if the head of the list (a) is smaller than b than it should return `(helper (cdr list) a)`, otherwise `(helper (cdr list) b)`. Now we can define `(min list)` as `(helper (cdr list) (car list))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (define (min list)
  (let imin ((l (cdr list))
         (m (car list)))
    (cond
     ((null? l) m)
     (else
      (let ((a (car l)))
        (imin (cdr l)
              (if (< a m) a m)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (min ns)
  (let loop ( (ns-left ns) (min-so-far maxint) )
    (if (null? ns-left)
      min-so-far
      (loop
        (cdr ns-left)
        (if (< (car ns-left) min-so-far)
          (car ns-left)
          min-so-far )))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (min list)
   (min-helper list #f))

(define (min-helper list min-so-far)
   (if (null? list) 
       min-so-far
       (let ((m (car list)))
            (if (eq? min-so-far #f)
                (set! min-so-far m))
            (if (< m min-so-far)
                (min-helper (cdr list) m)
                (min-helper (cdr list) min-so-far)))))
```